# How can I make a toggled element appear block at start, then toggle on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of 4 items, each item toggles to show a fly out. I would like the first item to be toggled (open) on load, then hovering keeps it open, but unhovering will close it. (followed by hovering re opens it as if it were a toggle.)

I have my list set up like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="targ">Target</li>
<li class="conn">Connect</li>
<li class="conv">Convert</li>
<li class="opti">Optimize</li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery to toggle the elements:

```
$(function() {
$('.targ, .target-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.target-popup').toggle(); 
});

$('.conn, .connect-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.connect-popup').toggle(); 
});

 $('.conv, .convert-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.convert-popup').toggle(); 
});

$('.opti, .optimize-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.optimize-popup').toggle(); 
});

});
```

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwknfekq/1/) as well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle with the solution:  https://jsfiddle.net/qwknfekq/5/

The idea is to show the item first, then handle the hover on both "over" and "out" states.

**UPDATE** 
You also need to hide the `.target-popup` any time you hover another button.

```
$(function() {
    $('.target-popup').show();
    $('.targ, .target-popup').hover(function() {
            $('.target-popup').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('.target-popup').hide();
        });

    $('.conn, .connect-popup').hover(function() {
        $('.target-popup').hide();
        $('.connect-popup').toggle();
    });

    $('.conv, .convert-popup').hover(function() {
        $('.target-popup').hide();
        $('.convert-popup').toggle();
    });

    $('.opti, .optimize-popup').hover(function() {
        $('.target-popup').hide();
        $('.optimize-popup').toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for the help! (5mins til I can accept answer)

Comment: Had an issue where initial popup didn't hide when hovering over sibling buttons. The updated code fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it

```
$(function() {
$('.targ, .target-popup').mouseenter(function() { 
    $('.target-popup').show(); 
});
$('.targ, .target-popup').mouseleave(function() { 
    $('.target-popup').hide(); 
});
$('.conn, .connect-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.connect-popup').toggle(); 
});

 $('.conv, .convert-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.convert-popup').toggle(); 
});

$('.opti, .optimize-popup').hover(function() { 
    $('.optimize-popup').toggle(); 
});

$(".target-popup").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('.target-popup').show()` to the bottom of your script or handle your hiding/showing via CSS then apply the correct class directly to the HTML.